# Theme recommendation: Hotel/Hostel/Bed & Breakfast

Tags: plugin-recommendation, theme-recommendation

I searched on different Marketplaces so far, but haven't found anything that wouldn't take me hours or even days to make a wordpress theme from.

#### Here's the list of things I need:

**1.** Slider or some photo gallery. Something fancy, eyecatching.

**2.** (Ajax?) Contact Form (minor issue - got some small plugin close to finished)

**3.** Registration/Booking

**4.** Maybe list the already booked dates.

**5.** Any other ideas what might be needed?

---

It can be for free or paid. Doesn't make any difference. If you know a theme or just a plugin that solves part of the issue: Tell me. Happy to upvote every single, tiny hint.

If you got search terms that might bring up better results on google or marketplaces, please tell me also. English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 3 & 4, try Booking Calendar: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/booking/. I just installed it on a site and it seems to work ok on first impression. It comes with a widget that shows a little calendar that shows dates that are booked, dates that someone has requested, and open dates. It also ships with a request form. It'll send emails when a request is made and when it is accepted or cancelled. I've only done a little testing, so I cannot completely vouch for it.

Answer (score 2):

For a slider, really liking Nivo Slider: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/features/#wordpress

I've also used Anything Slider, which I personally prefer for the stop/start feature when cycling items with text, but you'd have to build in the functionality yourself (whether with a category, a gallery, whatever): http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

Comment: I already used the nivo slider in a theme and it's really slick & nice to use. I'll need to find some time to build a class around it.